# Run a Notes Agent on the server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have developed a Notes Agent that does exactly what I desire when I run it on my Workspace.  The Notes database is on a domino server on our network.  I scheduled the Agent to run at a certain time and on the actual server but it did not run.  Why did the Agent not run as I specified the coreect server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agent's signer (that's your Notes id) has to have the right to execute (unrestricted) agents. Have a look in Domino Directory in server's document in security tab who is allowed to execute agents and sign the agent with such an id or let add your id to the list.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look at this.  Do I also have to enable the scheduled agents in File >> Preferences >> Background Configuration??

Comment: No, that's only for local scheduled agents which run on Notes Client.

Comment: Thanks. I have requested my company infrastructure person gives me permissions to run agents on the notes servers. Will let you know how I get on

Comment: I hope he does not allow you to run agents on the server. Nothing personally, but the agent should be signed using a special agent signer/runner ID, and *that* ID should be allowed to run agents on the server.
What if you leave the company and your ID get put in the deny access list? Every single agent signed by your ID will stop working...

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson Thanks for guidance.  I have spoken to the company Infrastructure person and they informed me that they will "sign the database with the server ID".  I am assuming this will mean it will not rely on my Notes ID to run

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thanks Knut.  I have them running now.  The security tab options had something to do with it as well as the signing

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure that the ID used to sign the agent actually has the rights to execute code on the server, you also need to make sure that the agent is only using backend classes.
Don't even declare any objects using the UI classes, or the agent will not run.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check `Notes Log` database (`log.nsf`, located on your server's root folder), section `Miscellaneous`, a document on time when your agent should be executed. Error message may give you a hint, what went wrong.
2. Make sure the signer of the agent has necessary permissions (to run scheduled agents on the server). This option can be set in the server document in the server address book (`names.nsf` located on your server's root folder).
3. If your agent involves any file and/or network operations, make sure that the signer of your agent has necessary permissions to run restricted operations (server document in the server address book). And check `Security` tab of your agent properties and enable `Allow restricted operations` flag.
4. Make sure that your agent **does not use** **any** UI-classes (NotesUIWorkspace, NotesUIDocument, etc) and neither use any script library that uses itself or refers to a library which uses UI classes. Only backend LotusScript classes are allowed for agents which run on the domino server context. Use of UI-classes in server agents lead to hard-to-catch errors for novices, when agent runs properly when launched manually, but does not work when is running as scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given nearly enough information for us to pin down the precise cause, so if the other answers don't help you, here is an old but still very useful article that you should refer to in order to help you understand more, maybe fix your problem yourself, and give you enough background about how things work so it will be easier for you to collect information for additional troubleshooting:

[Artcile About Troubleshooting Agents](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Troubleshooting_agents_ND5_6/index.html).

Pay particular attention to the section labeled **Common Problems**.

Comment: Thanks Richard I have this resolved but the link is helpful too